# Decryptor Function gives output a list of numbers instead of string

Tags: javascript, cryptography, cryptojs, password-encryption, rijndaelmanaged

I have a encryptor and decryptor function in my code as you can see below, it encrypts and decrypts a plain string using same algorithm `Rijndael-js` with the help of `crypto` and `PKCS7-Padding` packages. The encryptor function is working fine but a decryptor function should give me the original plain string which was encrypted with encryptor function.

**Here is my code**

```
import RijndaelManaged from 'rijndael-js'
import padder from 'pkcs7-padding'
import crypto from 'crypto'

let plainText, padded, keyData, ivData, cipher, encryptedData

const encryptor = async () => {
    plainText = Buffer.from('Here is my plain text', 'utf8')
    padded = padder.pad(plainText, 32)
    keyData = crypto.randomBytes(32)
    ivData = crypto.randomBytes(32)
    cipher = new RijndaelManaged(keyData, 'cbc')
    encryptedData = cipher.encrypt(padded, 256, ivData)
    console.log(encryptedData)
}
encryptor()

const decryptor = () => {
    const key = keyData
    const iv = ivData
    const encrypted = encryptedData
    const decipher = new RijndaelManaged(key, 'cbc')
    const decryptedPadded = decipher.decrypt(encrypted, 256, iv)
    const decrypted = padder.unpad(decryptedPadded, 32)
    const clearText = decrypted.toString('utf-8')
    console.log(clearText)
}
decryptor()
```

**Output of encryptor function**

```
[
  246, 222, 109, 114, 198, 100,  11,  68,
  181, 180,   9, 250, 188, 228, 215, 150,
   48, 141, 225,  32,   0, 118,  98,  54,
  235, 104, 196,   1, 146, 229, 122, 137
]
```

**Output of decryptor function**

```
72,101,114,101,32,105,115,32,109,121,32,112,108,97,105,110,32,116,101,120,116,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11
```

**Expected output of decryptor function**

```
Here is my plain text
```

I tried to `console.log` the `typeof` clearText variable it was `string`

Comment: Note that unpadding also fails (since PKCS#7 padding consists of non-printable characters you can only check this via the length or a hex encoding: `const clearText = Buffer.from(decrypted).toString('hex')`). Be aware that Rijndael with a blocksize of 256 bits is not AES and therefore not a standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const clearText = Buffer.from(decrypted).toString()
```